# getting errors installing Ruby on Rails on Windows, CentOS and Mint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, centos, linux-mint

I've had issues trying out ROR for 3 systems (CentOS, Mint and Windows) and all fail at different causes. I was thinking Windows would be the simplest but it just gives an error message `cannot load the file sqlite3` although sqlite3.exe does exist inside ruby's bin directory so I am confused.

With CentOS, I come across this error message after trying to issue
`rails new something`

```
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych(for YAML output).  
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.  
Invalid application name test.  
Please give a name which does not match one of the reserved rails words.
```

For that error, I followed setting guides posted here
http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/10/31/install-ruby-193-with-libyaml-on-centos/ and also reinstalled ruby, but once issuing the same command to create a ruby project as above, I get the same error.

With Mint, I got got a lot of error messages and tried solutions but none really worked, e.g.
[missing gems can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907248/missing-gems-can)

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Understand your frustration. Suggest opening different questions, 1 for each environment, and byte sized, so that all can focus.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with system paths, if you have it installed on the systems, but it's impossible to say without seeing the errors that you received. I'd try this tutorial, as it's the most comprehensive that I've seen: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book.

Comment: Windows is the *worst* Rails platform, IMO, although [railsinstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) seems to work well for people I've talked to. Without further details, it's difficult to know how to help you. I've never had an issue installing Rails on centos, never tried Mint.

Answer (score 2):

This area features continual change but as of June 2012 the most common development environment for rails is on a mac with OSX using items like xTools, homebrew and rvm to install ruby, rails and other packages.
See Alain's answer at
[Installing Ruby on Rails - Mac OS Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840719/installing-ruby-on-rails-mac-os-lion) and I really like
http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/ which is current enough and uses ruby 1.9.3

The second most popular choice is Linux, specifically Ubuntu which is now the recommended Unix desktop platform for Unix.
This post has the basics: http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/27/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-11-10/ though I would replace `1.9.2` to `1.9.3` for ruby.

Third is Windows.
Most people use railsinstaller for that - http://railsinstaller.org/

After those three, there are of course a variety of other Operating Systems such as CentOS and Mint, etc. but you're really going outside the mainstream (for RoR at least) with them so if you encounter problems there's a a much smaller community and less chance of a solution to problems.

Personally I've gone Windows -> Ubuntu -> Mac -> Ubuntu and I like Ubuntu the most.

btw
for editor I've gone Notepad -> Gedit -> vi
and for IDE I've gone Eclipse -> netBeans -> rubyMine
For source control git and not svn please.